# How do I get a log of Twilio Studio interactions,

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

How do I get the log of Twilio Studio interactions, specifically steps, I need to download it to analyze the performance of my IVR.

What I want to know is how many calls where resolve by one option of a split decision widget.

Is any way to download a CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API you can use to download such information. Take a look at the URL below, in particular Step.

[Studio REST API Resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api#studio-rest-api-resources)